# Pandas Plot for Subplots results in a Column title between the two subplots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Does anyone have any clue why the word "Category" is coming out in the attached picture? And why it is only above the bottom subplot rather than above both subplots?

This picture is an output from the following code

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,1)
plt.subplots_adjust(top = 0.9, bottom = 0.1, hspace = 0.6)
df_4g[['Free','Paid']].plot(kind = 'bar', stacked = True, figsize=(12,8), ax=ax[0])
df_4a[['Free','Paid']].plot(kind = 'bar', stacked = True, figsize=(12,8), ax=ax[1])
```

This is behind a big dataset where I have grouped by "Category" (i.e. the x-axis values) and "Type" (i.e. the Free and Paid stacked graph). I'm not really sure what else I would need to share to help assist in resolving this problem - the dataset is too large to share.

[image: Graph with word "Category" showing up]

Comment: I assume you just don't see the x-axis label "Category" below the lower subplot because the figure is cut off. Add `plt.tight_layout()` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

If you can provide a small sample dataset that will produce a figure with the same problem, it will be helpful.

Anyway, in your case, I guess the "Category" is actually the x-axis label for the top axes, please see the following example. You grouped your data by "Category", and after that, "Category" becomes the index name. By default, the index name will be used as the xlabel, see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html?highlight=plot#pandas.DataFrame.plot). I don't know why the bottom axes didn't have an xlabel without looking into your data.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abc'), 'B':[1,2,3], 'C':[3,2,1]})
df1.set_index('A', inplace=True)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abc'), 'B':[5,6,7], 'C':[1,2,3]})
df2.set_index('A', inplace=True)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,1)
plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.9, bottom=0.1, hspace=0.2)
df1.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, figsize=(12, 8), ax=ax[0])
df2.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, figsize=(12, 8), ax=ax[1])
```

[image]

If you don't want the x-axis label, you can set the corresponding `xlabel` parameter to an empty string "", such as:

```py
df1.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, figsize=(12, 8), ax=ax[0], xlabel='')
df2.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, figsize=(12, 8), ax=ax[1], xlabel='')
```